# Last outgoing call details after call ends

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi I searched a lot on this forum for correct result but unable to find. I need details of last outgoing call once call is ended. For this I am using BroadcasteReceiver here is code for my receiver

```
  public class CallStateBroadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ((TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}}
```

Here is code for PhoneStateListener

```
    public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

private Context context;

  public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context paramContext)
  {
    this.context = paramContext;
  }

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    ((TelephonyManager)this.context.getSystemService("phone")).listen(this, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state)
    {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500L);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,LastCallInfoActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.context.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Here is code for my activity which fetch call details for call log

```
    public class LastCallInfoActivity extends Activity{

String addtolist;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Cursor callDetailCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1");
    int phoneNumber= callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int callType=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int callDate=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int callDuration=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);


    Log.i(">>CAllDetails", "getsCallLogs" );

    if(callDetailCursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        while(callDetailCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String phoneNumberString=callDetailCursor.getString(phoneNumber);
            String  contactName= getContactName(this, phoneNumberString);
            String callTypeString =callDetailCursor.getString(callType);
            String callDateString=callDetailCursor.getString(callDate);
            String callDurationString=callDetailCursor.getString(callDuration);
            Date callDayTime=new Date(Long.valueOf(callDateString));

            int callCode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeString);
            int calldur=Integer.parseInt(callDurationString);
            if (callCode==2 && calldur>=1)
            {
                Double callCost=Double.parseDouble(callDurationString);


                String callCostString= String.valueOf( callCost);
                Log.i(">>CAllDetails", "getsLocation" );


                addtolist= "Name :"+contactName+"\n"+
                        "Phone Number: "+phoneNumberString+"\n"+"Call Duration :"+
                        callDurationString+" Seconds\n"+"Call Date: "+callDayTime+"\n"+
                callCostString;



            }
        }
    }callDetailCursor.close();

    Toast.makeText(this, addtolist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}

}
```

My this program show toast even before my call got disconnected and start my activity. Please help me and correct my code so that it will get executed after call ends 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

just try this add an additional if statement for checking previous sate was off hook.

```
 boolean wasoffhook=false;

  if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state)

   {
      wasoffhook=true;
    }
  if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state&&wasoffhook)
     {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(1500L);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,LastCallInfoActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    this.context.startActivity(intent);

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: your solutions is not working. it is not going in         if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state)

   {
      wasoffhook=true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

In your onreceive method of Callstatebroadcaster add this code and it would work fine.I just solved it.

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    try
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            Toast.makeText(context,"the no. is"+savedNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // onOutgoingCallStarted(context,"",callStartTime);

        }
        else
        {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;

            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        Log.d("Testing", "Outgoing call has been disconnect");
                        intent = new Intent(context, MyCustomDialog.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        System.out.println("CAll has been disconnect...............");
        //                            Toast.makeText(this, "CAll has been disconnect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
            {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in Callstatechanged method add this code.

```
  public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number)
{
    if(lastState == state)
    {
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state)
    {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
           // onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
           // onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
           // onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
          //  wasRinging = true;
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

            if (!wasRinging) {
                // Start your new activity
                onIncomingCallEnded(context,savedNumber,callStartTime,new Date());
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context,savedNumber,callStartTime,new Date());
            } else {
                onIncomingCallStarted(context,savedNumber,callStartTime);
                // Cancel your old activity
            }

            // this should be the last piece of code before the break

            break;


        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            if(isIncoming)
            {
               onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

This would work.